# Rows in mysql get overwritten, only the last one inserted is committed

Tags: mysql, razor, .net-core

I'm trying to insert data into a database, but only the last row gets committed. In the database, I have a table that has the IDs of the tour and the IDs of the attractions. So, when I try to insert a couple of rows with the same tour and different attractions, only the last one is inserted.

```
for (int i=ChosenAttractions.Count()-1; i>=0; i--)
{
TourAttractions newTourAttr = new TourAttractions();
newTourAttr.IdTourTA = NewTour.IdTour;
newTour.IdAttractionTA = (uint)ChosenAttractions[i];

await dbContext.TourAttractions.AddAsync(newTourAttr);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

When debugging, each iteration writes to the database, but the previous one is overwritten by the next one.

Comment: Where is the `mysql` code that has the problem?

Comment: @Luuk there's no mysql code; the project has a connection string for the database

Comment: And what about the DDL for your table? Does that have a unique key for tour?  (Which would explain only 1 tour is inserted)

Comment: No, there's no unique key for tour, and inserting multiple rows with the same tour id works in other places in the code(other pages), it's just this bit of code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that some of the entities weren't mapped correctly in the Context and Models (they were mapped as one-to-one, and it was supposed to be one-to-many). After I fixed that, the code started working correctly.